# JQuery Slider - How to also change the slider input value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

In addition to changing the input values on change of the slider ... how can I vise versa change the slider on input change in addition?

html:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <span style="float:right;"> 
        <input id="amount-min" type="number" placeholder="0.000" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:75px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
        <input id="amount-max" type="number" placeholder="0.000" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:75px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
    </span>
</div>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#amount-min" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
            $( "#amount-max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount-min" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
    $( "#amount-max" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

    $('#amount-min').on('change', function () {
        $(this).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
    });        

    $('#amount-max').on('change', function () {
        $(this).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });         

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e4gLmc2/

I want to keep the original range as given. And I want to only allow an input value that is within the range and considering the other value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change your `on change` to `on input`. Works better on `type number` inputs as you want the value to change immediately as the user changes the values in the inputs ( including with the arrows or up/down keys )

> This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Then just add `this.val()` ( which is the input val ) as low or high value of the `slider`

```js
$(function() {
     $("#slider-range").slider({
       range: true,
       min: 0,
       max: 500,
       step: 0.001,
       values: [35.113, 300.123],
       slide: function(event, ui) {

         $("#amount-min").val(ui.values[0]);
         $("#amount-max").val(ui.values[1]);
       }
     });
     
     $("#amount-min").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
     $("#amount-max").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
     console.log(
         $("#amount-min").val() );
     $('#amount-min').on('input', function() {
       if ($(this).val() < $("#amount-max").val()) {
         $("#slider-range").slider('values', 0, $(this).val());
       }

     });

     $('#amount-max').on('input', function() {
       if ($(this).val() > $("#amount-min").val()) {
         $("#slider-range").slider('values', 1, $(this).val());
       }
     });


   });
```

```html
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <span style="float:right;"> 
      <input id="amount-min" step=".001" type="number" placeholder="0.000" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:75px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
      <input id="amount-max" step=".001" type="number" placeholder="0.000" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:75px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
     </span>
</div>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a way to in addition only allow a min value that is smaller than the current max value ... and vice versa?

Comment: @PhilippM Yeah, that;s pretty simple. Just compare `this` val with the other input `val`. See edited answer. You can add an `else` to that `if` and do whatever you want in case of an error. Display a msg or smth like that

Comment: Great thanks. One last wish :-) ... how can I get it all on 3 decimals? ... so min 0.000 to max 500.000 and values: [75.000, 300.000] ... it not lets me if I change it likt this

Comment: @PhilippM add `step=".001"` to both the slider and the inputs. See edited answer